# NodeJs: Express generates new session for every request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm particularly new to nodejs and I'm trying to create this app with express-session and request module. This is the rough sample of my endpoints:

```js
app.get('/create-session', (req, res, next) => {
req.session.thing = 'something';
}

app.get('/get-session', (req, res, next) => {
res.json(req.session.thing)
}

app.get('/request-session' (req,res, next) => {
request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'localhost:3000/get-session',
    },
    (error, res, body) => {
    res.json(res)
    }
})
)}
```

So what happens is I call /create-session, making a session variable so that after I call /get-session a value will be returned. After that, I try to call /request-session, but no session data is retrieved. I'm not sure but I feel like a new session is generated for the request method that's why I'm not able to get the value. If I try to make a request for non-session data, I can retrieve it. I hope somebody helps me out on this one. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to so, can you add more info and some code of snippet so it will be easy to help and get the idea what you are trying to do!!

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS hello, I accidentally submitted the question while im still making it. My bad, already updated it.